# How to read IP addresses with countif?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, data-cleaning

Trying to write some VBA for automating a couple processes at work so I don't have to manually click all the time when I'm cleaning/screening data on Excel.

I've managed to get most of it to work but there's a section where I want the IP addresses to be read with the countif function -

At the moment I've got the following code:

```
Sub TestCountIf()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("COUNTIFS")
'apply the Excel COUNTIFS function
ws.Range("C2:C2000")= Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("C2:C2000),">=3
End Sub
```

Not 100% sure why it's not working but I'm a complete novice so it could be loads of reasons!

I tried deleting bits and changing the range to:

```
 ws.Range(C2, [C2000])
```

Comment: Your quotes and parentheses are off.

Comment: `ws.Range("C2:C2000")= Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("C2:C2000"),">=3")`  But that will fill the whole range with the same number.  I think you want your output somewhere else, other wise all the data in `"C2:C2000"` will be replaced.  Maybe something like: `ws.Range("Z2")= Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("C2:C2000"),">=3")`  Where `Z2` is the cell in which you want the result of the COUNTIFS.

Comment: Just a note that if the data in C2:C2000 is IP addresses with dots like `192.168.0.1`, they will not be recognized as numbers, so you can't use a number comparison like ">=3". The result of your CountIfs will always be 0.